# xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to read a XML string, edit it and save it as a XML file.

However I get the mentioned error in the title when I do `.write()`

I found out that when you read an XML string using `ElementTree.fromstring(string)` it will create an `ElementTree.Element` and not an `ElementTree` itself. An Element has no write method but the ElementTree does.

How can I write an Element to a XML file? Or how can I create an ElementTree and add my Element to that and then use the `.write` method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I found out that when you read a xml string using `ElementTree.fromstring(string)` it will actually create an `ElementTree.Element` and not a `ElementTree` itself.

Yes, you get the top-level element back (also called the "document element").

> An Element has no `write` method but the `ElementTree` does.

The [`ElementTree` constructor signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree) goes like this:

```
class xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree(element=None, file=None)
```

Therefore it's completely straightforward:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

doc = ET.fromstring("<test>test öäü</test>")

tree = ET.ElementTree(doc)
tree.write("test.xml", encoding="utf-8")
```

You always should specify the encoding when writing an XML file. Most of the time, UTF-8 is the best choice.

Comment: Thank you. This worked! Not sure why I did not find this myself.

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps anyone who gets this unclear error message when trying to use ElementTree to write an xml file, and spends way too long on it (like I did):

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 788, in _get_writer
write = file_or_filename.write
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

... in my case, it was simply because the path to the directory I was trying to write my xml file to did not exist! For example:

```
tree.write("/FolderDidNotExist/test.xml", encoding="utf-8")
```

a simple `mkdir /FolderDidNotExist` did the trick. No more error. (Of course, this error message could use some "love" so I'm posting this here in case I forget what it means again [which I've done] and need to google this again)

Comment: You saved me a lot of time!